# I am facing module databricks.sdk has no attribute runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, databricks

I have seen the source code databricks-sdk has runtime module in it. Still when I am writing the tests for a python code where I import
`from databricks.sdk.runtime import dbutils` I am facing databricks.sdk has no attribute runtime.

I am using `with patch('databricks.sdk.runtime.dbutils') as 'dbutils_mock' :`

I was expecting this will work because runtime is within databricks.sdk
Git repo : https://github.com/databricks/databricks-sdk-py/blob/main/databricks/sdk/runtime/__init__.py#L13